# BootstrapValidator solo muestra mensaje y no color ni icono

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Buen día
Mi problema es el siguiente
Al momento de validar un campo con bootstrapValidator solo me muestra el texto en negro :

[image]

> al momento de mandar el input vacío me muestra el mensaje y eso esta correcto

lo que quiero es que muestre algo asi:

[image]

Se que el problema podria ser el css pero ya puse el cdn css de bootstrap Validator:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
```

Este es mi codigo html:

```
                                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <h7>Modelo</h7>
                                                                <input type="text" id="Modelo" name="Modelo" class="form-control" placeholder="Modelo" autocomplete="off" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
```

y Este es mi codigo JS:

```
  $('.RegisterForm').bootstrapValidator({
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        Modelo: {
            message: 'The username is not valid',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                      message:'The username is required and cannot be empty'
                }
            }

        }
    },

});
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar ,Gracias de Antemano
Saludos

> Actualización

Estos los links de css que utilizo:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<!-- Include FontAwesome CSS if you want to use feedback icons provided by FontAwesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<!---Css-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/AdminLTE/Bower_Components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js")%>"></script>
<!--Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback" />
<!--Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<!--Ionicons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" />
<!--Tempusdominus Bootstrap 4 -->

<!--iCheck -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/icheck-bootstrap/3.0.1/icheck-bootstrap.css" />
<!--JQVMap -->
<!--Theme style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/admin-lte/3.1.0/css/adminlte.min.css" />
<!--overlayScrollbars -->
<!--Daterange picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2-bootstrap-theme/0.1.0-beta.10/select2-bootstrap.css" integrity="sha512-CbQfNVBSMAYmnzP3IC+mZZmYMP2HUnVkV4+PwuhpiMUmITtSpS7Prr3fNncV1RBOnWxzz4pYQ5EAGG4ck46Oig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<!--datatables-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />

<link href="AdminLTE/Bower_Components/icheck-1.0.3/skins/flat/red.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="AdminLTE/Bower_Components/bootstrap-datepicker-1.9.0-dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="AdminLTE/Bower_Components/filepond-master/filepond-master/dist/filepond.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/overlayscrollbars/1.13.1/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css" integrity="sha512-jN4O0AUkRmE6Jwc8la2I5iBmS+tCDcfUd1eq8nrZIBnDKTmCp5YxxNN1/aetnAH32qT+dDbk1aGhhoaw5cJNlw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lamentablemente BootstrapValidator No es compatible con bootstrap 4 en su lugar opte por utilizar jqueryValidator